# Annotation position does not work in faceted ggplot2 with inherit=FALSE

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, facet

I have a simple faceted plot from the following data

```
structure(list(Entity = c("Africa", "Americas", "Eastern Mediterranean", 
"Europe", "South-East Asia", "Western Pacific"), meandeaths = c(93.9, 
0.0821, 1.47, 0, 4.02, 0.569)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I used the code here to add a single annotation at the bottom of the plot. Unfortunately, the annotation appears in each of the facets, although I have used inherit = TRUE in the aes.

library(ggfittext)
library(ggtext)
library(extrafont)
library(extrafontdb)
library(tidyverse)

```
plot_label <- 'Africa is the world region that is most affected by malaria: in 2019, 96% of global deaths from malaria occurred on the African continent.' %>% 
    str_wrap(width = 50)
   
   
     colors_palette <- c(
    "Africa"= "#01FF70", 
    "Americas" = "#FFDC00", 
    "Eastern Mediterranean" = "#FF851B", 
    "South-East Asia" = "#F012BE",
    "Western Pacific" = "red",
     "Europe" = "skyblue")
    
   common_theme <- function() {
    theme_minimal() + 
     theme(
      text = element_text(color = "#FFFFFF"),
      strip.text = element_blank(), 
      axis.text = element_blank(), 
      axis.title = element_blank(),
      panel.grid = element_blank(),
      plot.title = element_markdown(family = "Century Gothic", size = rel(7.5), face = "bold",  color = "#EF476F", hjust = .5, margin = margin(t = 1,b = 1, unit = "cm")),
      plot.subtitle = element_markdown(size = rel(3), face = "bold", family = "Century Gothic",  hjust = .5, margin = margin(t = .25, b = .25, unit = "cm")), 
      plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#111111", color = NA)
     )
   }
   

plotmal %>%   
     mutate(Entity = as.factor(Entity)) %>%  
    
     ggplot(aes(x = 3, fill = Entity)) + 
     geom_col(
      aes(y= meandeaths),
      color = NA
     ) + 
     geom_col(
      aes(y = 1),
      alpha = .35, 
      color = NA
     ) + 
     ggtext::geom_richtext(
      aes(.2, 0, 
          label = glue::glue("<span style ='font-size: 35px;'>{str_to_title(Entity)}</span><br><span style='font-size:27.5px;'>{round(meandeaths,2)}%</span>"),
          color = Entity
      ),
      family = "Century Gothic",
      fill = NA,
      label.size = 0, 
      label.color = NA,
      lineheight = 1.5
     ) + 
     
     annotate(geom ="text", x = 1.2, y =-1.5, label = plot_label, 
             size = 4.5, family = "Century Gothic" ,fontface = "italic", color = "#FFFFFF", lineheight = .95,inherit.aes = FALSE 
     
     )+ # inherit.aes = FALSE does not work
     
     labs(
      title = "Silent Killer",
      subtitle = "Global Malaria Deaths by Region 2000-2020",
      caption = "Data:OurWorldinData | Viz: @stepminer2"
     ) +
     scale_x_continuous(
      limits = c(0.2, 3 + 0.5)  
     ) +
     scale_fill_manual(
      values = colors_palette,
      guide = "none"
     ) + 
     scale_color_manual(
      values = colors_palette,
      guide = "none"
     ) + 
     coord_polar(theta = "y") + 
     facet_wrap(vars(Entity), nrow = 2) + 
     common_theme() +
     theme(
      plot.margin = margin(t = .5,b = 1, unit = "cm")
     )
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `ggplot2::annotate` or `ggplot2::annotation_custom` will add to each facet and using `inherit=FALSE` will not change that.

But one option to overcome this would be the `gggrid` package which unlike `ggplot2::annotate` or `ggplot2::annotation_custom` allows for placing different grobs on each facet or as in your case to place a label on only one facet. To this end:

1. Create your label as a `textGrob` which also allows to use relative coordinates to place your label.
2. Add this label to your plot via `gggrid::grid_panel`. Here you could pass a `data.frame` to the `data` argument which contains only an `Entity` column and which is used to specify the panels where you want to add the label, i.e. in your case `"Europe"`.

```
tg <- grid::textGrob(plot_label,
  x = unit(0, "npc") + unit(2, "mm"),
  y = unit(0, "npc") + unit(2, "mm"),
  just = c("left", "bottom"),
  gp = grid::gpar(fontsize = 4.5 * .pt, fontfamily = "Century Gothic", col = "#FFFFFF", lineheight = .95)
)


plotmal %>%
  mutate(Entity = as.factor(Entity)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = 3, fill = Entity)) +
  geom_col(
    aes(y = meandeaths),
    color = NA
  ) +
  geom_col(
    aes(y = 1),
    alpha = .35,
    color = NA
  ) +
  ggtext::geom_richtext(
    aes(.2, 0,
      label = glue::glue("<span style ='font-size: 35px;'>{str_to_title(Entity)}</span><br><span style='font-size:27.5px;'>{round(meandeaths,2)}%</span>"),
      color = Entity
    ),
    family = "Century Gothic",
    fill = NA,
    label.size = 0,
    label.color = NA,
    lineheight = 1.5
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Silent Killer",
    subtitle = "Global Malaria Deaths by Region 2000-2020",
    caption = "Data:OurWorldinData | Viz: @stepminer2"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    limits = c(0.2, 3 + 0.5)
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = colors_palette,
    guide = "none"
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = colors_palette,
    guide = "none"
  ) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  facet_wrap(vars(Entity), nrow = 2) +
  common_theme() +
  theme(
    plot.margin = margin(t = .5, b = 1, unit = "cm")
  ) +
  gggrid::grid_panel(tg, data = data.frame(Entity = "Europe"))
```

[image]

**UPDATE** If you want your annotation to span the whole width of the plot I would go for a `patchwork` approach where the annotation is created as a second plot and glued to the main plot.

Note: For the annotation plot I use `geom_textbox`. I also dropped the `str_wrap` which IMHO does not make any sense in this case.

```
p_main <- plotmal %>%
  mutate(Entity = as.factor(Entity)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = 3, fill = Entity)) +
  geom_col(
    aes(y = meandeaths),
    color = NA
  ) +
  geom_col(
    aes(y = 1),
    alpha = .35,
    color = NA
  ) +
  ggtext::geom_richtext(
    aes(.2, 0,
      label = glue::glue("<span style ='font-size: 35px;'>{str_to_title(Entity)}</span><br><span style='font-size:27.5px;'>{round(meandeaths,2)}%</span>"),
      color = Entity
    ),
    family = "Century Gothic",
    fill = NA,
    label.size = 0,
    label.color = NA,
    lineheight = 1.5
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = colors_palette,
    guide = "none"
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = colors_palette,
    guide = "none"
  ) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  facet_wrap(vars(Entity), nrow = 2) +
  common_theme()

p_anno <- ggplot(data.frame(x = factor(1), y = factor(1)), aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_textbox(label = plot_label, color = "white", fill = "#111111", lineheight = .95, 
               family = "Century Gothic", size = 4.5, width = unit(1, "npc"), box.colour = NA,
               halign = .5) +
  common_theme() +
  theme(
    plot.margin = margin(t = .5, b = 1, unit = "cm")
  )

library(patchwork)

p_main / p_anno + plot_layout(heights = c(20, 1)) &
  plot_annotation(
    title = "Silent Killer",
    subtitle = "Global Malaria Deaths by Region 2000-2020",
    caption = "Data:OurWorldinData | Viz: @stepminer2",
    theme = common_theme()
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Looks OK. Thanks. I would have preferred a paragraph that spans the whole width of the plot, but that will do.

Comment: Haha. In that case we could go for `patchwork`. See my edit.

Comment: Great, thanks. Exactly what I wanted. You're the Man!